# Redimensionar imagen en base64 con PHP

Tags: php, base64

Estoy intentando redimensinar una imagen capturada desde un input file pero no me hes posible, la imagen la guardo en mi base de datos codificada en base64 sin problema pero no me redimensiona la imagen, carga los valores originales ¿Cómo puedo conseguir que tome las medidas que indico en las variables?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php 

include 'conexion.php';


if(isset($_POST['imgsave'])){

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $celular = $_POST['celular'];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $password=hash('sha512', $password);
    $aviso=$_POST["aviso"];
    $fecha_registro=$_POST["fecha_registro"];
    $codigo=$_POST["codigo"];
    $activo=$_POST["activo"];
    $nAncho = 430;
    $nAlto = 350;

    /* Subir INE a Carpeta */
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $route = "public/ine/".$file_name;

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$route);

    /* Subir Selfie en Base64 */
    
    $imagen_original = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'];

    $img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagen_original);
    $ancho_original = imagesx($img_original);
    $alto_original = imagesy($img_original);

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($nAncho, $nAlto);
    imagecopyresized($tmp, $img_original, 0,0,0,0, $nAncho, $nAlto,
    $ancho_original, $alto_original);

    
    if(move_uploaded_file($imagen_original, 'temp') === true){
     $getimg = base64_encode(file_get_contents('temp'));
    
    $insert = "INSERT INTO users(nombre, apellidos, email, celular, password, name, img, aviso, fecha_registro, codigo, activo)
     VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$email', '$celular', '$password', '$file_name', '$getimg', '$aviso', '$fecha_registro', '$codigo', '$activo')";

   

    //Verificar que no se repita el email en la base de datos
        $verificar_email = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_email) > 0){
            echo '
                <script>
                alert("Este correo ya esta registrado, intenta con otro diferente");
                window.location = "../registro/index.php";
                </script>
            ';
            exit();
        }

        //Verificar que no se repita el celular en la base de datos
        $verificar_celular = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE celular='$celular' ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_celular) > 0){
            echo '
                <script>
                alert("Este celular ya esta registrado, intenta con otro diferente");
                window.location = "../registro/index.php";
                </script>
            ';
            exit();
        }    
       
       $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $insert);
      
       if ($ejecutar) {   
           echo '
               <script>
               alert("Para activar tu cuenta revisa tu email, si es necesario busca en el Spam.");
               window.location = "../registro/index.php";
               </script>
           ';
       }else{
           echo '
               <script>
               alert("Intenta nuevamente, usuario no registrado");
               window.location = "../registro/index.php";
               </script>
               ';
       }
   
       mysqli_close($conexion);
    
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo. Por un lado creas `$tmp`, que es la imagen que has subido a la cual le has aplicado el resize que querias hacerle, pero por el otro luego no haces nada con esa variable `$tmp`.  No la guardas ni la muestras ni nada de nada.  ¿Tu que quieres hacer con ella después?  Si la quieres guardar entonces haz el `base64_encode` sobre `$tmp` y no sobre la imagen original. O sea, `$getimg = base64_encode($tmp);`

Comment: Hola masterguru, al hace el base64_encode sobre $tmp no lo codifica, y al dejar la variable $getimg si me aplica el encode.